# How to add icon to admin root menu in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm developing a module witch should have a menu in root admin panel of prestashop , we have developed it and we see the "New tab" between other menu tabs but we want to add an icon to this "New tab" like other tabs !

For example states has an icon near it but "New tab" doesn't have (Please Look at image).

[image: Example]

```
$tab = new tab();  
$tab->id_parent=0;  
$tab->name=array(); 
foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
    $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']]=$name;  
}  
$tab->class_name=$class_name;  
$tab->module=$this->name;  
$tab->active=1;  
$tab->add();
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must indicate the icon in your CSS file, like this:

```
.icon-AdminName:before {
  content: "X";
}
```

**Note:** Replace `AdminName` with your class name specified in `$tab->class_name`.

Comment: Yes , that was great , beside , we should create one of admin hooks and load css file in it  , thank you